# Live video streaming from IP camera

Tags: android, video-streaming, live

I have internal web server running, that stores "http:/xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/cam_1.jpg" pictures, all I want to do is get those jpg pictures in my android phone and with high refresh rate to make a live stream video.

Any thoughts or ideas, how can I achieve this, would be appreciated :)

I am doing this example, source code:
http://www.anddev.org/resources/file/1484

But I stuck on getting only one image(if I rotate screen image changes)

Comment: Why I get negative feedbacks? I did something wrong?

Comment: You have not showed us what you have tried, any code you have created to achieve this and any sources you have researched. This is NOT a site on which you can expect people to do all your work for you

Comment: Ohh, ok then this is what I've done:(will edit in 1minute)

Comment: It would be much easier to copy/paste the part of your code that is not working on this question and not a link to download it

Comment: I know, but the thing is that code works, but just does not what it suppose to do :/. JPG's does not refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find myself, change .jpg to .cgi and it works perfectly :)